# Finding function to obtain invertibility of the conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Suppose I have a random variable $y\in\mathbb{R}$, and I can write the conditional expectation of $y$ on another random variable $x$, $E[y|x]$.

**Question 1**: If I had to choose a function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ so that $E[g(y)|x]$ is invertible in $x$, which properties or form should $g$ have? **Question 2**: More specifically, is it "weakly better" to choose an invertible function vs a non-invertible function $g$?

On the first question, I doubt there is a closed form answer, but I don't really know how to start addressing it. On the second question, in two special cases the conjecture is true:

1. If $x=y$, then $E[g(y)|x]=g(x)$, hence $E[g(y)|x]$ is invertible in $x$ if and only if $g$ is invertible on the support of $y$.
2. Suppose $y|x$ first order stochastic dominates $y|x'$ for any $x>x'$, then $E[y|x]$ is invertible in $x$ (as "better" $x$ in a FOSD sense have a larger conditional expectation). And a strictly increasing $g$ (a specific form of invertibility) preserves this invertibility: $E[g(y)|x]>E[g(y)|x']$ whenever $x$ FOSD $x'$.

But what about the general case? For question 2, in general, one would have to show that whenever $E[g(y)|x]=\int g(y) f(y|x) dy$ (where $f$ is the density) is invertible in $x$ for a non-invertible function $g$, then it should also be invertible for an invertible function $g$ (or find a counterexample). And I have no idea which approach to take.

Comment: In your second bullet, I think you mean "for any $x > x'$" ratehr than "for any $x\neq x'$.  Also, invertible is not always possible, such as when $Y$ and $X$ are independent.

Comment: If $X$ is uniform over $[0,1]$ and $P[Y=x|X=x]=P[Y=-x|X=x]=1/2$, then $E[Y|X=x]=0$ for all $x$, but $E[Y^2|X=x]=x^2$ and from this you can ascertain $X$.  So sometimes it is better to use a noninvertible function $g(Y)=Y^2$ rather than an invertible $g(Y)=Y$.

Comment: Very good! You provided the counterexample: An invertible function is not at least as good as a non-invertible function at creating an invertible conditional expectation. So the conjecture in question 2 is not in general correct. Thanks. That leaves question 1: If invertibility is not a property that makes $g(.)$ at least as good as a non-invertible function, how should we choose $g(.)$ or how could we approach this problem? (I know this is very vague.)

Comment: (On the first comment.) True, invertibility is not always possible: If the joint distribution of $y$ and $x$ is given then we cannot do anything about that. I was just wondering about the case where $(y,x)$ are related and we can choose the $g$-function freely - the rest is beyond our control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My above comments show it is sometimes better to use non-invertible $g$ functions.  Here I treat a portion of the question 1.

---

Consider the discrete case $X \in \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}$ where $x_i$ are distinct and $P[X=x_i]>0$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$.  Invertibility of $E[g(Y)|X=x_i]$ requires the conditional CDF function $F_i(y) = P[Y\leq y|X=x_i]$ to be distinct for all $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$.  Indeed, if there are two indices $i \neq j$ such that $F_i(y)=F_j(y)$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$, then we could not distinguish $E[g(Y)|X=x_i]$ from $E[g(Y)|X=x_j]$, regardless of the function $g$.

Now suppose the CDF functions $F_i(y)$ are all distinct and for simplicity assume they have (distinct) PDFs $f_i(y)$. We want to construct a function $g(Y)$ such that $E[g(Y)|X=x_i] = \int g(y) f_i(y)dy$ is distinct for all $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$. Does such a $g(Y)$ always exist?

There are many approaches.  One way is to assume the densities $f_i(y)$ are square integrable and then represent each function $f_i(y)$ as a sum of $k$ orthonormal basis functions $\{b_1(y), ..., b_k(y)\}$ (where $k \leq n$):
$$f_i(y) = \sum_{j=1}^k a_{ij} b_j(y)  \quad, \forall i \in \{1, ..., n\} $$
The basis functions can be found, for example, by the Gram-Schmidt procedure. Now define $g(y) =\sum_{m=1}^k \theta_m b_m(y)$.  Then: 
$$ \int g(y) f_i(y)dy = \sum_{j=1}^k \theta_j a_{ij}  \quad, \forall i \in \{1, ..., n\} $$
Define the $n\times k$ matrix  $A = (a_{ij})$.  Then $A$ has distinct rows (since the $f_i(y)$ functions are distinct for each row $i$).  Define  $\theta$ as the column vector $(\theta_1, ..., \theta_k)$.  Define $c_i = \int g(y) f_i(y)dy$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$ and define $c$ as the column vector $(c_1, ..., c_n)$.  Then: 
$$ A\theta = c$$
The question reduces to this:  If a matrix $A$ has distinct rows, is it always possible to find a vector $\theta$ such that $A\theta$ has distinct entries?  The answer is "yes."  In fact we can choose $\theta$ randomly with iid coefficients in the interval $[0,1]$ and the probability that this random selection works is 1.

---

Alternatively: Define the matrix $D=(d_{ij})$ with $d_{ij}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_i(y)f_j(y)dy$.  Let $\theta = (\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_n)$ be a vector (to be chosen later) and define $g(y) = \sum_{j=1}^n \theta_j f_j(y)$. Notice that for each $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$, the value $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(y)f_i(y)dy$ is the $i$th row of $D\theta$.

1) If the $D$ matrix has distinct rows, you can randomly choose $\theta$ with entries i.i.d. in $[0,1]$ and the probability that $D\theta$ has distinct rows is 1.

2) If the $D$ matrix is invertible, then you can choose $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ as any vector with distinct entries and choose $\theta = D^{-1}c$.

Comment: Great, thanks! That's an approach I never would have been able to come up with. I have two questions on this. First, how does $\int g(y)f_i(y)dy=\sum_{j=1}^k=\theta_ja_{ij}$ follow from your definitions? Maybe I don't understand enough of the basis functions, but how do you integrate those $b_j(y)$ "out"? Second, the existence of the $\theta$ vector such that $A\theta$ has distinct entries: I think I understand, but the answer isn't entirely obvious to me. The idea is that, because the rows of $A$ are distinct, we can choose almost any vector $\theta\neq0$ such that $A\theta$ is distinct?

Comment: Since $\{b_1(y), ..., b_k(y)\}$ are orthonormal we have for all $i,j \in \{1, ..., n\}$:  $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} b_i(y)b_j(y) dy = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
0 &\mbox{ if $i\neq j$} \\
1  & \mbox{ if $i=j$} 
\end{array}
\right.$$

Comment: Let $r_i$ and $r_j$ be distinct rows of $A$, then $r_i \theta = r_j \theta$ if and only if $(r_i-r_j)\theta = 0$, which happens if and only if $\theta$ lies in a $(n-1)$-dimensional hyperplane of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  To make it more obvious, you can choose $\theta_i$ i.i.d. Gaussian and use the fact that the sum of i.i.d. Gaussians is Gaussian.

Comment: Great, thanks, these comments make sense. So with this approach, the question boils down to whether the densities of the $y$'s are square integrable so that we can write the problem with the basis functions. Once that is possible, it is almost always possible to find a function $g(y)$ (represented by vector $\theta$) so that the conditional expectation is invertible. I think I have to read up on these basis functions, but thank you so much for the thorough answer!

Comment: Dear Micheal, I posed another question, related to your answer, because I did not want to prolong this thread here. Perhaps you can have a look, I'd be very grateful, thanks! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191698/representing-conditional-density-function-with-orthonormal-basis-functions

Comment: If you want to get more insight without any orthonormal basis stuff, just look at the "Alternatively" part of my answer and suppose the $D$ matrix is invertible.

Comment: Yes I got that, thanks, but the orthonormal stuff peaked my interest for now. ;)