# Representing conditional density function with orthonormal basis functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request

Based on an answer I got to [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2181150/finding-function-to-obtain-invertibility-of-the-conditional-expectation), I was wondering if I understood the approach correctly.

Consider the conditional density function $f(y|X=x_i)$. The claim in the answer was that if $f(y|X=x_i)$ is square integrable, then it can be represented as a sum of $k$ orthonormal basis functions $b_j(y)$ with $j=1,...,k$ and coefficients $a_{ij}$ such that
$$f(y|X=x_i)=\sum_{j=1}^k a_{ij}b_j(y).$$

I understand why this should work in some cases, but not in general. First, suppose $y$ is discrete with $k$ different values. Then $f(y|X=x_i)$ is just the conditional probability mass function and we can easily set $a_{ij}=f(y_j|X=x_i)$ [a scalar] and $b_j(y)=1$ if and only if $y=y_j$. **Q1**: Is this the idea or is there something deeper that I am missing?

**Q2**: But, second, if $y$ is continuously distributed conditional on $x_i$, then this representation with $k$ (finite) basis functions can at best be an approximation (except in special cases like uniform densities), or am I wrong? So the implicit assumption is that this representation only works exactly for discrete random variables (and in this case it really requires $k$ basis functions except if several $y_j$ have the same density)?

**Q3**: Can you recommend some easily accessible literature/textbooks that explains this basis function representation for square integrable functions (and perhaps square integrability while we are at it)? Thanks!

Comment: One difficulty is that you are asking a question about an equation given as $f(y|X=x) = \sum_{j=1}^k a_j b_j(y)$, an equation that has an "$x$" on one side and no "$x$" on the other side.  So the equation looks strange and makes the question confusing.  Also your equation  $a_j = f(y_j|X=x)$ seems to have an $x$ occuring only on one side, so I do not know how to respond.

Comment: In general, the idea of finding an orthonormal basis for square integrable functions $\{f_1(x), ..., f_n(x)\}$ is _exact_ (not an approximation) and is done by the Gram-Schmidt procedure, see any book on abstract linear algebra like "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Axler.  For example from the polynomial functions  $\{1, x, x^2\}$ over $x \in [0,1]$ you can make 3 orthonormal polynomial functions $\{g_1(x), g_2(x), g_3(x)\}$ with the same span.

Comment: For the case when $Y$ can only take values in a finite set, you are working with vectors instead of functions, and usual linear algebra applies.  Like finding an orthonormal basis for the span of $\{(1/2,1/2,0), (1/3,1/3,1/3), (1/6, 3/6, 2/6)\}$.

Comment: Thank you, I addressed your first comment with an edit. The $f(y|X=x_i)$ and $a_{ij}$ now both refer to a specific $x_i\in X$ via the subscript $i$. Does what I am writing make sense now? If so, then I think I understood the discrete case and that the coefficients are scalars (taken together a vector). I will look into this textbook. Thank you so much!

Comment: The $a_{ij}$ index uses $j \in \{1, \ldots, k\}$ to index the $b_j(y)$ functions and does not relate to $y$. For example suppose $X \in \{1,2\}$ and $Y \in \{1,2,3\}$ and $(P[Y=1|X=1], P[Y=2|X=1], P[Y=3|X=1])=(1/2, 1/2, 0)$ and $(P[Y=1|X=2], P[Y=2|X=2], P[Y=3|X=2])= (1/3, 1/3, 1/3)$.  You can find an orthonormal basis $\{\vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2\}$ for the span of $\{(1/2, 1/2, 0), (1/3,1/3,1/3)\}$ and then $(1/3,1/3,1/3) = a\vec{v}_1 + b\vec{v}_2$ and $(1/2,1/2,0) = c\vec{v}_1 + d\vec{v}_2$.